# Error in read data from text file and write result in a text file by C#

Tags: c#

I wanna to read a text file which has `8935900` lines(like following one), line by line and put the data in matrix (multidimensional array) and save it in text file  as the first column is (i) and and second column is (j) column(z[i][j]) and the third column shows the value of this position in array.for example `z[1][0] = 0.123413`

```
1 0 0.123413
1 1 0.23423413
1 2 0.2234413
2 0 0.7456413
2 1 0.987651
2 2 0.0358413
3 0 0.4876513
3 1 0.986443
3 2 0.3465413
```

I wrote an script and I have 2 questions:

1- Is the logic of the code is correct?

2- if it is correct; it shows an error `"The process cannot access the file 'C:\\----1000.txt' because it is being used by another process" -IO exception was unhandled`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace _2test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;

            double[,] a = new double[89359, 100];

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\joao.txt");
            for(int x=1;x<=8935900;x++)
            {
              line = file.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(' ');
                int i=0;
                int j=0;
                foreach(string value in values)
                {
                    i = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                    j = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                    a[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
                }

                var valuess = a.OfType<double>();
                using (var filestream = new FileStream("1000.txt", FileMode.Create))
                using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
                {
                    foreach (double value in values)
                        streamwriter.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you don't have the file opened in another window, when using your code, since that is causing the error

Comment: FileStreams and StreamReaders need to be closed when you are done with them. Use the `using` idiom for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(a)` will write your Array's type not the current value to the `Console` (then to the text file). Instead change your code like this:

```
   // define i and j here
   int i, j;
   foreach(string value in values)
   {
      i = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
      j  = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
      a[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
   }
```

Then change this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

To:

```
Console.WriteLine(a[i, j]);
```

And instead of creating a new `FileStream` and `StreamWriter`, you can do it after your loop finished. First populate your array.Then after the foreach loop:

```
var allValues = a.OfType<double>();
using(var filestream = new FileStream("1000.txt", FileMode.Create))
using(var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
{
    foreach(double value in values)
           streamwriter.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Here is the full code!

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        double[,] a = new double[89359, 100];
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\joao.txt");
        for (int x = 1; x <= 8935900; x++)
        {
            line = file.ReadLine();
            string[] values = line.Split(' ');
            int i, j;
            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                i = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                j = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                a[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
            }
        }

        var allValues = a.OfType<double>();
        using (var filestream = new FileStream("1000.txt", FileMode.Create))
        using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
        {
            foreach (double value in allValues)
                streamwriter.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Selman22. Then If I want to see the result in text file (in shape of matrix) what should i do?

Comment: @user3280040 that's a different story.if you have another questions then ask a new question :)

Comment: you mean i change it to following one?:  int i=0; int j=0;          foreach(string value in values) { i = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
j = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
a[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
}
Console.WriteLine(a[i, j]);
var valuess = a.OfType<double>();
using (var filestream = new FileStream("1000.txt", FileMode.Create))
using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
{
foreach (double value in values)
streamwriter.WriteLine(value);
}
}

Comment: @user3280040 change your foreach loop with my code.then delete all console and filestream codes inside of foreach.put that code `(starting with var values = a.OfType<double>();)` outside of your loop.

Comment: It shows  errors :cannot convert type of 'string' to 'double' in this line //foreach(double value in values)// and also some of variable are the same and used before like values @selman22

Comment: @user3280040 you are mixing the loops! that should be different loop! CHANGE YOUR FIRST LOOP with the first code in my answer. then add the second loop outside of your foreach loop!

Comment: @user3280040 TAKE A LOOK I ADD THE **FULL** CODE